# What means Range error on my Release pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When the release pipeline run end up with this error
RangeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value "4294967295" is invalid for option "size".
I don't know what means this error

[task failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spHAk.png)
[Log of the task failed when release run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QwPU.png)

Comment: A few more details would be great, otherwise there isn't enough information to work with. Does this happen in a certain task? what are you releasing and what tasks do you use? Can you share a screenshot or even better logs?

Comment: @D.J. I write an answer to paste the images of the errors. Task: Azure App Service deploy and Task version: 4*

Comment: I added two images with the logs and error @D.J.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me using Web Deploy to a nodejs app service.
Web Deploy worked at first, until we added some packages in our package.json (e.g. "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons")

Then our release pipeline suddenly outputs "64-bit = +" in the deployment log.
If we remove the packages, the "64-bit = +" is gone, and our Web Deploy works again.

Image of log from Release pipeline

[image: 1]

Not sure how to resolve it, but in our case we used Zip Deploy instead like @Ari Gunawan recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to deploy a node app to Azure App Service from release pipeline. Not sure what the error means as there are no further details about it but I resolved it by using "Zip Deploy" deployment method and "Continue on error"
[image]